# I'm struggling to implement the distributeCards method in my Uno game, can I please have some suggestions as to how I should approach the method?

Tags: java

The method is supposed to iterate through the playerHand array and draw a new random card using playerHand[i][j] = new UnoCard until each player’s hand is of size START_HAND. I should also be able to fill each player’s hand before moving to the next one.

I've tried setting it up the way I have below, but I am unsure of where I should go to successfully get my result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static int nPlayers;
    public static int currentPlayer;
    public static UnoCard playerHand[][];
    public static UnoCard currentCard;
    public static final int CARDS_IN_DECK = 112;
    public static final int START_HAND = 7;
    public static boolean direction = true; // true for regular direction, false for reverse direction
    public static int winner;

    public Uno(int nPlayers) {
        this.playerHand = new UnoCard[nPlayers][CARDS_IN_DECK];
        this.currentPlayer = 0;
        this.nPlayers = nPlayers;
    }

public static void distributeCards() {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerHand.length; i++) {
            playerHand[][] = new UnoCard();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the problem? The text basically tells you what to do: iterate over all players and set each player's hand before moving to the next, i.e. iterate over all "hand" slots and assign a random card to them. The "hardest" part would be to maintain a collection of undealt cards and selecting one randomly.

Comment: This is probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem you're having, but I'll try to help either way.

It doesn't look you're filling the array correctly. Since you have a 2D array, you need a nested loop to do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < playerHand.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < playerHand[i].length; j++){
        playerHand[i][j] = new UnoCard(); 
    }
}
```

Note the `[i][j]` in the assignment - we're assigning the card to a specific cell in the 2D array.

Comment: For clarity I'd probably rename `i` to `p` (for player) or even `playerIndex` (or similar) and `j` to `c` (for card) or `cardIndex` etc. - just so it's clear what those indices mean. :)